# How can I add a script launcher to the top bar?

Tags: gnome, launcher

I have a Ruby script, which starts a server and opens a browser. It runs without any problems when called from terminal, but when I try to add a launcher to the top bar of the classic GNOME desktop, with the properties set as in the picture below, and click on it, the program does not run.

How can I add a launcher to the tap bar?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the generic Command to run a script/executable be `language-interpreter path_to_application` instead of `path_to_application`?

I'm not familiar with ruby, but I suppose it would give `ruby path_to_application` in your case.

Comment: In the file, I have a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. Is this not enough?

Comment: I followed your suggestion but it still did not work.

Comment: To be honest I'm not quite sure, that's why my answer is written like a question. (since I'm an unprivileged user, I can't comment anything else than my own questions/answer) As far as I understand it, Command need to be a valid executable in this case (which a script isn't without the interpreter) while the interpreter would be called properly in terminal using a proper shebang.

Comment: Can you try the Hard Way described in the [Launcher documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToAddaLauncher)?