# How do I launch my script from a launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, scripts, ruby

I have my custom script in Ruby with read permission, which starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

I can run that script from the terminal by typing that path. I added a file with `.desktop` extention to `/usr/share/applications` with content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Foo
Comment=Foo
Exec=/path/to/the/script
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

and permission 777. When I open the Ubuntu file/application searcher at the top-left corner, I find my script by typing in the name. But when I click on it, it does not run. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may believe the content is appropriate but there is no way we can know unless you show us. You should also mention the permissions of the .desktop file.

Comment: I added that information, but I don't think the problem is with that part because I had the same problem with adding a launcher to the menu bar with an older Ubuntu, which I asked on this site about , about an year ago: http://askubuntu.com/questions/329232/how-can-i-add-a-script-launcher-to-the-top-bar, and it has not yet been solved.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what exactly is "content that I believe is appropriate". However, if you can run the script through terminal all you have to do is create a script with:

```
#!/bin/bash    
cd /path/to/folder
command-you-would-run-in-terminal
```

Make the script executable. Then in your .desktop file, launch the script instead of your command directly.

Example

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=path/to/icon/bash script
Name=Script name
path/to/icon/here
Comment=A description here
```

Comment: The script cannot be Ruby but has to be bash?